# What is best practice to translate Role Base ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, roles, role-based-access-control

I create role base access control and I want to translate this role for user like this

```
"CanCreateUser" translate to اضافة مستخدم
"CanUpdateUser" to تعديل مستخدم
```

and so on

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you pls explain the saying `translate this role for user` ? Save this words into database? Display them in the website or anything else?

Comment: yeah I want to Display all role by Arabic language

Comment: Then, is it an option to write logic code in page like `if(role =="CanCreateUser" ){role = اضافة مستخدم} else if(){xxx}` ? I mean you've realized role based controller, that means the response of access controller can get the role information.